# How to link custom python function to the create button of form view in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to call this python method when user click on 'create' button

```
def _validate_remaining_area(self):
    for land in self:
        if (land.remaining_area <= 0):
            raise ValidationError('You cannot more plot in this land')
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `create` button, you mean standard odoo `Model` `create` method, then override that model's `create` method and call your method there.

For example (`res.partner` model):

```
from odoo import models, api


class ResPartner(models.Model):
    """Extend to modify create method."""

    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        """Override to call _validate_remaining_area."""
        record = super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
        # Assuming this method is defined in res.partner model..
        record._validate_remaining_area()
        return record
```

Comment: if i override `create` button functionality. its old functionality will work or not?

Comment: Yes if you call super as in example.